# list all directories containing *.html files and also list the files in the directories

Tags: find

I would like to obtain the list of all the directories which contains HTML documents, finished `.htm` or `.html` ignoring upper or lower case.

I have tried:

```
find / -type d -ls | tr -s [:blank:] | cut -d ' ' -f 11 | grep -i -e "*.htm" -e "*.html"
```

But it only lists directories, and I need to list those directories' content and I don't know how.

I have then tried:

```
find / -type d -exec ls -l {} \; | tr -s [:blank:] | cut -d ' ' -f 9 | grep -i -e ".htm" -e ".html"
```

And it does find them, but how do I print the directories where they are?.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some possible commands including example output

The most simple:

```
$ find / -iname "*.htm*"
foo/a.HTM
foo/b.HTML
foo/b.html
foo/x.htmx
foo/a.htm
bar/a.htm
```

`-iname` means to find files matching glob and be case insensitive. The problem is the glob `*.htm*` also finds `htmx`.

To prevent finding `htmx` you have to split the glob:

```
$ find / -iname "*.htm" -o -iname "*.html"
foo/a.HTM
foo/b.HTML
foo/b.html
foo/a.htm
bar/a.htm
```

Or use grep which can use regex:

```
$ find / | grep -i "\.html*$"
foo/a.HTM
foo/b.HTML
foo/b.html
foo/a.htm
bar/a.htm
```

Note that regex is different than glob. Especially the dot (`.`) and star (`*`) have very different meanings in glob and regex.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)#Compared_to_regular_expressions for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Using `zsh`:

```sh
setopt extendedglob nullglob
for pathname in /**/*(/e{'[[ -n $REPLY/(#i)*.htm(l#)(#q.) ]]'}); do
    printf '%s:\n' $pathname
    ls -l $pathname
done
```

This prints the pathname of each directory containing any regular file whose name ends with either `.htm` or `.html` (regardless of case), followed by the `ls -l` output for that directory.

The loop loops over every directory in or beneath `/` that contains a HTML file.  It does this using the `/**/*` glob which, by itself matches everything in the whole `/` directory hierarchy.  This list is filtered to only contain directory pathnames by the `/` glob qualifier (the initial `/` in the first parenthesis), and the list is further filtered to only contain those entries for which `[[ -n $REPLY/(#i)*.htm(l#)(#q.) ]]` is true.  This expression, where `$REPLY` is one of the directory pathnames being examined, will be true if a directory contains at least one regular file with either a `.htm` or `.html` filename suffix (case insensitively).

The `e{...}` part of the globbing pattern could probably be written more succinctly.

---

Using `bash`:

```sh
shopt -s globstar nullglob extglob nocaseglob
for pathname in /**/*/; do
    set -- "$pathname"/*.htm?(l)
    if [[ -f $1 ]]; then
        printf '%s:\n' "${pathname%/}"
        ls -l "$pathname"
    fi
done
```

This uses the `globstar` shell option to enable the use of the `**` globbing pattern (enabled by default in the `zsh` shell).  It iterates over all directory pathnames in the whole directory hierarchy from `/` down and tries to expand the `*.htm?(l)` glob in each directory (this matches the HTML files we're interested in).  If the first match of this glob is a regular file, or a symbolic link to one, then the directory pathname and the `ls -l` listing is outputted.

If you may have *directories* with the `.htm` on `.html` filename suffix, you would have to test the matches of the expansion inside the loop in a separate loop, just to make sure you catch any regular files (or symbolic links to regular files) with the HTML suffixes:

```sh
shopt -s globstar extglob nocaseglob
for pathname in /**/*/; do
    for match in "$pathname"/*.htm?(l); do
        if [[ -f $match ]]; then
            printf '%s:\n' "${pathname%/}"
            ls -l "$pathname"
            break
        fi
    done
done
```

I've deleted the `nullglob` shell option in this variation since we do no longer depend on it.

---

In the POSIX `sh` shell you don't have access to the `**` glob, so you would have to use `find` to generate the directory pathnames for the loop:

```sh
find / -type d -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        for match in "$pathname"/*.[hH][tT][mM] "$pathname"/*.[hH][tT][mM][lL] ; do
            if [ -f "$match" ]; then
                printf "%s:\n" "${pathname%/}"
                ls -l "$pathname"
                break
            fi
        done
    done' sh {} +
```

Here, `find` acts like a sort of pathname generator for the embedded `sh -c` script and feeds it with pathnames of directories.

The `sh -c` script does pretty much what the 2nd `bash` variation of the answer does, i.e. it iterates over the expansion of the glob that should match the wanted names, testing each name to see whether it's a regular file (or a symbolic link to one).  Once it finds a file it prints the directory pathname followed by the `ls -l` output.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using

```
find / '(' -iname '*.htm' -o -iname '*.html' ')' -printf '%h\n' | uniq | xargs -r -d '\n' ls -l
```

The first part, `find / '(' -iname '*.htm' -o -iname '*.html' ')' -printf '%h\n'`, finds all files that end with `.htm` or `.html` in upper or lower case (using glob patterns), and prints the directory (`%h`) for each such file found, one directory per line.

Because of how `find` scans directories, there are one or more consecutive identical directories listed; `uniq` retains only one of each.

Finally, we feed the list of directories to `xargs`, telling it to not run a command without any directories `-r`, and that the separator is a newline `-d '\n'`. The command is `ls -l`; modify to your liking.

If you only need the list of directories, not those directories contents, drop the `xargs` part:

```
find / '(' -iname '*.htm' -o -iname '*.html' ')' -printf '%h\n' | uniq
```